# UIAutomatorviewer throws error

Tags: appium, uiautomatorviewer

I need your support to remove this error which is keep on coming while I'm using uiautomatorviewer.bat file for inspecting elements. It is working for only static page of an application. When i was taking screenshot of a page where numeric value is display & it is changing dynamically it throws same error again.

**Error :**
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

[Dynamic Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E4mO.png)

Following things i have already tried but it didn't work :

1. Stop Appium server in the background.
2. Disconnected mobile device & connect it back.
3. Close the uiautomatorviewer.bat file & restart it again.

Please guys help me!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean to say you press capture screenshot button after the page becomes static or after taking screenshot you change the values dynamically?

Comment: Application is capturing dynamic values continuously . So once the page is opened i clicked on screenshot button but it throws error constantly for only dynamic pages.